# await Task.Delay() doesnt work. Dialog close immediately

Tags: c#, winforms, async-await

Hi. I have winforms app. In the app I have input form. A would like to simulate delay after click OK button. But code is running and form is close immediately after click. Pls help.

**Button has set DialogResult to OK**. I use ShowDialog to display form.

```cs
//btn click handler
private async void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    customer.UserName = "testing";
    await Task.Delay(30000);
    //await Task.Run(()=> System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(30000)); //I tried this too
    return;
}
```

Comment: Well what's closing the form? All you've shown is a button click handler...

Comment: @JonSkeet I bellieve the DialogResult closes the form.

Comment: Do you want to close the form after a certain amount of time while maintaining responsiveness or what is the exact goal of the delay?

Comment: As @CSharpie commented, you have probably set the the `DialogResult` property for this button, which means it will close the form when clicked. Also, you most likely don't want to do this, but instead override the `OnFormClosing` method to cancel or delay closing (since user can still close the form using the close button in the form titlebar).

Comment: Dialogs don't just close on their own. There's some other code that you're not showing that is doing it. Unless you can show this code we can't answer the question. If you can show this code then you can probably answer the question yourself.

Comment: I will send data to DB from this form..so I would like simulate delay. I dont like frozen form (GUI)...so I trying async/await.

Form is closed by DialogResult.

Comment: @Enigmativity If you set DialogResult property form is close after you hit the button. You don´t need to write anything else.

Comment: You've already accepted an answer, but hopefully you can see how you could have avoided confusion by providing a [mcve] which we could have run ourselves to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @JonSkeet I think I wrote all needed information. But thanks for link.

Comment: @BeranekCZ: It depends on whether you want to make it easy for people to help you, and make your question more valuable for future readers. Personally, I'd encourage both, as a matter of respect for those trying to help you, and to make the world a better place in general. (I wasn't aware offhand that setting the `DialogResult` property had that effect. If you'd provided a short but complete example, I could have easily worked out what was going on and helped you. There's a big difference between "the bare minimum required" and "all the information to make a question good".)

Comment: @BeranekCZ - The code that you needed to post was `this.btnOk.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;`. When Jon Skeet gives you a suggestion you should probably follow it. There's no-one with more rep points that he has - he knows what he is talking about. The purpose of SO is to provide good quality questions and answers _for future readers_ - not just yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dialog closes once the `btnOK_Click` method returns since the button has its `DialogResult` property set.

And the `btnOK_Click` method returns as soon as `Task.Delay` **started** the delay because it's an `async` method. At which point the dialog closes and it appears as if the `Task.Delay` didn't work.

To stop that from happening you could remove the `DialogResult` property from the button and set the parent form's `DialogResult` to `OK` after the `await` statement and then manually call the `Close` method.

```
private async void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    customer.UserName = "testing";
    await Task.Delay(30000);

    DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    Close();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As you don't actively call Close() from your btnOK_Click I assume you have set the Button.DialogResult property to DialogResult.OK:

From [MSDN Button.DialogResult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.dialogresult%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

> If the DialogResult for this property is set to anything other than
>   None, and if the parent form was displayed through the ShowDialog
>   method, clicking the button closes the parent form without your having
>   to hook up any events.

This also closes the form if you do have hooked up an event.

A better method would be to remember that you are closing and start a System.Windows.Forms.Timer. The Timer.Tick event handler can check whether you are closing; set the DialogResult property and call Dialog.Close()